# Large enough images break the Gaming blog layout.

Tags: bug, status-declined, design, blog

[image: Broken page layout]

I'm afraid tables (yes, *actual tables* <3) also might cause this very same issue.

Comment: Uf. If we keep finding design bugs, then Jin'll never get around to [our lasers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/make-the-mothership-shoot-its-lasers-on-hover)...

Comment: Too bad we can't place bounties on this meta, that'd sure tempt him

Comment: I thought I had put a max width on the images in the post section.. I'll take a look.

Comment: @Jin, this image was probably carried over from the old design as a  draft. So that might have mixed things up a little

Comment: @Ivo i checked. for the images in the single view post, i did put a max-width on it. but i didn't do this for the homepage. i'll fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Not to be pedantic, but you shouldn't post images larger than the correct size for the post anyway -- if you resize them in CSS that is wasted bandwidth.

The proper thing to do is post the correct width images, then have the image link to larger sizes.

Comment: Jin is using this design as a guideline for all other future blog designs; that's why I didn't fix this myself by editing the post instead. It's just better to fix this once for all images for all blogs in my opinion.